# DFS algorithm continues recursive call, does not return

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

I am writing DFS in JavaScript, and the algorithm finds the node, but the return statement simple ends the current recursive call, and it continues onward to keep searching the tree.

```
dfs(node, target = 0) {
    if (node) {
      if (node.data === target) {
        return node;
      } 
      console.log(node.data);
      this.dfs(node.left, target);
      this.dfs(node.right, target);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Correct. Now what is the problem and what have you done to try and solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return in a recursive call the result of the recursice call (which sounds like a tautology). In this case, I assume the result is a node or `undefined`, which tries first the node itself, then the left part and at last the right part.

```
dfs(node, target = 0) {
    if (node) {
        if (node.data === target) {
            return node;
        } 
        console.log(node.data);
        return this.dfs(node.left, target) || this.dfs(node.right, target);
    }
}
```